# Gitlab secret detection, how to test it works

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have gitlab secret detection, and i wanted to check it works. I have spring project and the job set up. What kind of secret pattern would it pick up.

Does anyone know how i can check it actually picks something up?

I have tried adding the following to the code, its made up, but doesn't get flagged:

```
aws_secret=AKIAIMNOJVGFDXXXE4OA
```

Comment: This is a complete list of patterns https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/secrets/-/blob/master/gitleaks.toml

Comment: @mx0 thanks, my exmaple matches the regex but doesnt seem to flag it in my most recent commit. its in code as well as in applicaiton.properties file

Comment: I never used it but it should produce an artifact after scanning https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportssecret_detection

Comment: Have you configured the project for security scanning?

Comment: @sytech configured?  whats do you mean? It is placed in the pipeline as a step and runs. i believe that should be enough.

Comment: @mx0 yes it should do, the stage passes i cant get it to fail. So from the console output it seems as though its scanning. But just not flagging an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the secrets detector finds a secret, it doesn't fail the job (ie, it doesn't have a non-0 exit code). In the analyzer output, it will show how many leaks were found, but not what they were. The full details are written to a file called `gl-secret-detection-report.json`. You can either `cat` the file in the job so you can see the results in the Job output, or upload it as an artifact so it gets recognized as a sast report.

Here's the secrets detection job from one of my pipelines that both `cat`'s the file and uploads it as a sast report artifact. Note: for my purposes, I wasn't able to directly use the template, so I run the analyzer manually:

```yaml
Secrets Detector:
  stage: sast
  image:
    name: "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/secrets"
  needs: []
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - main
  before_script:
    - apk add jq
  script:
    - /analyzer run
    - cat gl-secret-detection-report.json | jq '.'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-secret-detection-report.json
```

The `gl-secret-detection-report.json` file looks like this for a test repository I set up and added a GitLab Runner registration token to a file called `TESTING`:

```json
{
  "version": "14.0.4",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "138bf52be327e2fc3d1934e45c93a83436c267e45aa84f5b55f2db87085cb205",
      "category": "secret_detection",
      "name": "GitLab Runner Registration Token",
      "message": "GitLab Runner Registration Token detected; please remove and revoke it if this is a leak.",
      "description": "Historic GitLab Runner Registration Token secret has been found in commit 0a4623336ac54174647e151186c796cf7987702a.",
      "cve": "TESTING:5432b14f2bdaa01f041f6eeadc53fe68c96ef12231b168d86c71b95aca838f3c:gitlab_runner_registration_token",
      "severity": "Critical",
      "confidence": "Unknown",
      "raw_source_code_extract": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "scanner": {
        "id": "gitleaks",
        "name": "Gitleaks"
      },
      "location": {
        "file": "TESTING",
        "commit": {
          "author": "author",
          "date": "2022-09-12T17:30:33Z",
          "message": "a commit message",
          "sha": "0a4623336ac54174647e151186c796cf7987702a"
        },
        "start_line": 1
      },
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "type": "gitleaks_rule_id",
          "name": "Gitleaks rule ID gitlab_runner_registration_token",
          "value": "gitlab_runner_registration_token"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scan": {
    "analyzer": {
      "id": "secrets",
      "name": "secrets",
      "url": "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/secrets",
      "vendor": {
        "name": "GitLab"
      },
      "version": "4.3.2"
    },
    "scanner": {
      "id": "gitleaks",
      "name": "Gitleaks",
      "url": "https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks",
      "vendor": {
        "name": "GitLab"
      },
      "version": "8.10.3"
    },
    "type": "secret_detection",
    "start_time": "2022-09-12T17:30:54",
    "end_time": "2022-09-12T17:30:55",
    "status": "success"
  }
}
```

This includes the type of secret found, what file it was in and what line(s), and information from the commit where the secret was added.

If you wanted to force the job to fail if any secrets were found, you can do that with `jq` (note: I install `jq` in the `before_script` of this job, it's not available in the image by default.):

```yaml
Secrets Detector:
  stage: sast
  image:
    name: "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/secrets"
  needs: []
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - main
  before_script:
    - apk add jq
  script:
    - /analyzer run
    - cat gl-secret-detection-report.json | jq '.'
    - if [[ $(cat gl-secret-detection-report.json | jq '.vulnerabilities | length > 0') ]]; then echo "secrets found" && exit 1; fi
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-secret-detection-report.json
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks. I wonder what the purpose of the template is if you can't make it fail the job...

Looks like you can use `/analyzer run --indent` to get a nicer formatted report without jq, however I don't see an option to return non-zero on detection. You could grep for a string such as `raw_source_code_extract` which only appears when a secret is matched but that seems quite brittle. You also can't easily grep the output of the tool directly because of the coloured text. So +1 for your jq solution.